# Are public keys stored in the browsers in macos 11.4 and in iOS 14

Tags: ios, macos-catalina, webauthn

I have tested https://webauthn.io/ on my mac and iphone. On iPhone I could register with Chrome and sign in with Safari but on macos I had to register separately on Chrome and Safari.

I wonder where the public keys are stored and why the behavior is different on macos and ios?

Comment: At least the browsers are entirely different on macOS whereas on iOS the engine is system-provided, they all run on Apple-provided engine and just change the UI. They aren’t allowed to provide their own browser engine so they may share some resources behind the scene

Comment: Hi Umut, it's actually the private keys that are stored on your devices. The public keys are stored by the website, in this case webauthn.io.

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up through macOS Big Sur WebAuthn credentials are indeed siloed to individual browsers. In practical terms this means a Touch ID credential registered in Safari cannot be used when authenticating in Chrome, nor a Chrome one in Edge (Chromium). Touch ID must be registered per browser, and a credential ID is only valid for the browser it was registered in.

As you noted iOS gained an OS-level credential store in 14.5 (if I remember correctly), similar to Windows Hello. This had the added benefit of allowing WebAuthn to be used in *all* browser apps, not just Safari.app, and Touch ID only needed to be registered once for authentication in any browser app.

I’ll end this by saying that the upcoming preview of Apple’s iCloud Keychain-backed “passkeys” appears to offer a Windows Hello-esque OS-level credential store in macOS Monterey that is sorely needed:

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10106

Comment: Thanks! Well written. Do you have any reference documentation that I can read up more?

Comment: Unfortunately no, most of this is what I've learned the hard way, first-hand, based on personal (and professional) experience working with the WebAuthn API. The best resource that comes to mind wrt WebAuthn in Apple land, though, is this WebKit article published in Oct 2020: https://webkit.org/blog/11312/meet-face-id-and-touch-id-for-the-web/

Comment: Actually there is only one browser on iOS. This is probably why the credentials are shared between apps using that browser. Like Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Aha, so that's why it seems like it's an OS-level store? Things will get messy on iOS too if Apple ever has to open things up to other browser engines